# Setting POST or GET request data to a QueryDict in the manage.py shell

Tags: python, django

The `django.http.HttpRequest` object in the `manage.py shell` does not have a `GET` or `POST` attribute. Is there really no way of setting the same `POST` or `GET` data as in my Django views from one of its urls to a `QueryDict` in the `manage.py shell`?

Comment: Did you try something like `setattr(request, 'GET', my_dict_full_of_params)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you paste what you are typing? I'm able to add data to the `GET` dictionary.

```
(stackoverflow)➜  my_project  python ./manage.py shell
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.http import HttpRequest
>>> req = HttpRequest()
>>> print req
<HttpRequest
path:,
GET:{},
POST:{},
COOKIES:{},
META:{}>
>>> req.GET['test'] = 'hello world'
>>> print req
<HttpRequest
path:,
GET:{'test': 'hello world'},
POST:{},
COOKIES:{},
META:{}>
>>>
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't instantiate `HttpRequest`! I didn't know `GET` or `POST` are instance attributes. Thank you.